# How to upload a file using filesystem I/O in Mean app?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, fs

I am using fs for uploading a file in my web app but the console shows that the file has been saved to the desired location which I have entered but the file doesn't show up there.

The code is here:-

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var path = require('path');

module.exports.updatePhoto = function(req,res) {
var file = req.files.file;
var userId = req.body.userId;

console.log("User "+ userId +" is submitting ", file);
var uploadDate = new Date();

var tempPath = file.path;
var targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../uploads/" + userId + uploadDate +file.name);
var savePath = "/uploads/" + userId + uploadDate + file.name;

fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath,function(err){
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
else {
   User.findById(userId, function(err, userData){
       var user = userData;
       user.image = savePath;
       user.save(function(err){
           if(err) {
               console.log("failed")
               res.json({status: 500})
           }
           else {
               console.log("saved");
               res.json({status: 200})
           }
       })
   })
}
})
};
```

Comment: You should post the code you have already done so we can review it. I have done this before and have it working.

Comment: The code has been added by me. Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using connect-multiparty to get the file from Express? https://github.com/expressjs/connect-multiparty

I ended up loading the files to AWS. So the best I can offer is the code to do that. It is basically free for my usage and I use docker to rebuild my site so this make it more flexible.

My File.Js:

```
    'use strict';

module.exports = function (app) {

  /**
   * Module dependencies.
   */
  var auth = require('../config/auth'),
    api = {},
    multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
    multipartyMiddleware = multiparty(),
    path = require('path'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    S3FS = require('s3fs');

  var s3fsImpl = new S3FS('FOLDER_NAME_ENTER_HERE', {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  });

  /**
   * Saves the logo file to the server
  */
  api.uploadImage = function(req, res) {
    // We are able to access req.files.file thanks to the multiparty middleware
    var folder = req.params.folder;
    var file = req.files.file;

    var filename = uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.name);
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
    s3fsImpl.writeFile(folder + '/' + filename, stream).then(function () {
      fs.unlink(file.path, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      });
      return res.status(200).json({'fileName': filename, 'url': 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/AWS_FOLDER_ENTER_HERE' + folder + '/' + filename});
    });
  };

  /**
   * Routes
   */
  app.route('/api/files/:folder/uploadImage')
    .post(auth.jwtCheck, multipartyMiddleware, api.uploadImage);

};
```